# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "gamusino"?

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, animales

El DLE, desde 1956,  define **gamusino** como

> Animal imaginario cuyo nombre se usa para dar bromas a los cazadores novatos.

Aparece en las siguientes ediciones, hasta la actual, sin variar un ápice, salvo la adición de la marca *Esp.* en la edición electrónica actual.

Sin embargo, no hay ninguna indicación de su etimología, ni siquiera negativo (origen incierto, etimología discutida, etc.).

¿Cuál es su origen?

Comment: Me pregunto si tendrá relación con *gamuza*.

Comment: Yo diría que es una variante de _gamo_, que es un tipo de ciervo, muy popular en caza mayor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según veo en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamusino) y algún otro [artículo](https://www.javierlorente.es/gamusino/), probablemente se relaciona con el provenzal *gambosi*, que significa "engaño".